# R : rgl displaying issue (black windows) on linux

Tags: linux, r, opengl

I installed the rgl package for R on my new computer running on Linux Mint 17. I followed the advices found on several forum as I already did on my previous computer to solve my issues. So, rgl is installed and correctly loaded (without message). But the opened windows does not display anything. This is a corrupted windows

Screenshot:

[image]

I have never seen that, there is no error to help me to understand the problem. When I upscale the windows it becomes black...

Comment: Do you have OpenGL libraries installed and set up properly? Type `glxinfo |grep direct` in the terminal. What is the output?

Comment: Yes I have. OpenGL works well. `glxgears` works,  `glxinfo | grep direct` output is `direct rendering: Yes`

That's the problem. Everything is fine. OpenGL, rgl and R are in the same version as in my old computer.